Distorted layout for videos on iOS with every browser
As you can check in the screenshot, the video has a random issue that not always appears (actually is from time to time) that make the video element smaller than it should (it must take the whole page).

The app is done in React and the video element doesn't have anything special.
I've checked the issue in every browser and it happens in the most used (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, ...).
Moreover, I've tested the possibility of a CSS change once the page is already loaded to force the video gets the whole div but no luck.
onPlay={() => {

          if (!videoRef?.current?.style) return;
          setTimeout(function () {
            videoRef.current.style.width = '99,9%';
            videoRef.current.style.display = flex;
          }, 1000);
        }}

I opened an issue in the Feedback Apple portal but no answer yet.
It only happens on iOS devices, do you know what is happening?
